# How can I register a generic object factory?

Tags: .net, generics, autofixture, open-generics

I have the following two classes:

```
public class KeyedEntity<TEntity>
{
    internal KeyedEntity() { }

    public Identifier Key { get; set; }
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public static class KeyedEntity
{
    public static KeyedEntity<TEntity> Create<TEntity>(Identifier key, TEntity entity)
    {
        return new KeyedEntity<TEntity>
        {
            Key = key,
            Entity = entity,
        };
    }
}
```

The reason the constructor is `internal` and the second class exists is I want to enforce the more highly-maintainable `KeyedEntity.Create(x, y)` syntax rather than `new KeyedEntity<T>{ Key = x, Entity = y }`. (Note that the type is inferred with the former syntax.)

I want to tell AutoFixture how to create an instance of `KeyedEntity`. However, the `Register` method only seems to allow registration of a single type rather than an open generic type.

How can I register `KeyedEntity.Create<TEntity>` as the creation function for `KeyedEntity<TEntity>`?

Comment: Why do you consider `KeyedEntity.Create<T>(x, y)` more maintainable than `new KeyedEntity<T>(x, y)`?

Comment: @Mark: A factory method may return a (future) subclass, a constructor will never.

Comment: @eFloh Ah, I actually hadn't considered that, since I never design my code around subclassing (*favor composition over inheritance*) :)

Comment: @MarkSeemann, because C# supports type inference for methods, whereas it doesn't for constructors.

Comment: @Sam It saves you a few keystrokes, but how does it make your code more *maintainable*?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092446/autofixture-configuring-an-open-generics-specimen-builder

Comment: @MarkSeemann, it comes down to the DRY principle; if I change something, I want to minimise the number of places in which I have to change it. In this case, if I change the type of something that I add to a new `KeyedEntity`, with type inference, I don't need to change the call to `KeyedEntity`.

Comment: @Sam If you have calls to `new KeyedEntity<Foo>(x, y)` all over the place, you have a tightly coupled system. Creating a static, concrete factory doesn't solve *that* problem. It sounds to me like you're attempting to address a symptom instead of a root problem.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I don't have calls to it all over the place. However, I do have multiple calls to it in the application's data access layer. I think it's inevitable that use of a DTO produces tight coupling to the DTO. Are you suggesting I use an interface for the DTO? I'm keen to hear what you think the underlying problem is; I don't usually get useful feedback on my work.

Comment: @Sam IME, making a constructor internal and exposing a concrete factory method rarely provides much benefit. Now your code is more complicated than before, and I don't believe that you've gained much.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks. I'll consider that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support your open generic type, you can write a custom *Specimen Builder*:

```
public class KeyedEntityBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly static MethodInfo createMethod =
        typeof(KeyedEntity).GetMethod("Create");

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;
        if (t == null ||
            !t.IsGenericType ||
            t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(KeyedEntity<>))
            return new NoSpecimen(request);

        var entityType = t.GetGenericArguments().Single();

        var key = context.Resolve(typeof(Identifier));
        var entity = context.Resolve(entityType);

        return createMethod
            .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { key, entity });
    }
}
```

(Defensive coding omitted for clarity.)

The following unit test passes:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CreateKeyedEntity()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(new KeyedEntityBuilder());

        var actual = fixture.Create<KeyedEntity<Foo>>();

        Assert.NotNull(actual.Key);
        Assert.NotNull(actual.Entity);
    }
}
```

For better maintainability, you should encapsulate [`KeyedEntityBuilder` in a Customization](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a set of derived types, e.g.:

```
public class A: KeyedEntity<A>
{
}

public class B: KeyedEntity<B>
{
}
```

<del>Since the above object graph contains a circular reference (on `T`) you need to configure the `Fixture` instance to omit assignments on first recursion:</del>

<del>Then you</del> Create a generic method that will customize the creation algorithm for `KeyedEntity<T>`:

```
internal void CustomizeKeyedEntity<T>(IFixture fixture)
{
    fixture.Customize<KeyedEntity<T>>(c =>
        c.FromFactory(() =>
            KeyedEntity.Create(
                fixture.Create<Identifier>(),
                fixture.Create<T>())));
}
```

You may use the above method as:

```
this.CustomizeKeyedEntity<A>(fixture);
this.CustomizeKeyedEntity<B>(fixture);
```

**Example**

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    this.CustomizeKeyedEntity<A>(fixture);
    this.CustomizeKeyedEntity<B>(fixture);

    var actualA = fixture.Create<A>();
    var actualB = fixture.Create<B>();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that circular reference?

Comment: This still looks like it has the same problem as just using the `Register` method; it doesn't allow for open-generic registration. I know I could still just make a registration for each constructed/closed generic type I want to use, but that isn't as maintainable as I would like. I might see if I can improve the question so it's clear that it's about registering an open generic type and factory.

Comment: @Sam There is not much you can do (yet) with open generics (see [this thread](https://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/3387)). However, as [Mark Seemann wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209469/how-can-i-register-a-generic-object-factory/20211376#comment30137336_20209469) you may consider `new KeyedEntity<T>(x, y)`.

Comment: If `A` and `B` are defined as in the answer, `KeyedEntity<A>` exposes a property of type `A`, etc. Where's the circular reference in that?

Comment: I see... it was the result of the `CustomizeKeyedEntity<T>` (notice the last `fixture.Create<T>()`. Thank you - I will update the answer.